# Retrieving data from DynamoDB table in swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on an iOS app. I am writing all my code in Swift and using Amazon DynamoDB for storage purposes. I currently have a table in DynamoDB with objects in it. What exactly is the code to query across the table and add all items in that table into an array. I'm basically trying to pull certain components from these objects and create a table view with each cell representing an object. My current attempt is below, but it fails to actually put anything in the table (none of the cells show up).

```
 self.matches = []

        let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()
        let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
        queryExpression.limit = 100;
        dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(DDBMatch.self, expression: queryExpression).continueWithBlock({ (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in

            if task.result != nil {
                let paginatedOutput = task.result as! AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput

                for item in paginatedOutput.items as! [DDBMatch] {
                    //NSLog(item.M!.stringValue)
                    self.matches.append(item)
                }

                if ((task.error) != nil) {
                    print("Error: \(task.error)")
                }
                return nil

            }


            return nil
            })


        for item in self.matches {
            NSLog(item.M!.stringValue)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: put a `tableView.reloadData()` **after the loop** containing `self.matches.append(item)`.

Comment: thank you so much! @luk2302